# Getting syntax highlighting, Code Lens and refactoring in typescript comment

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

In the example below I can rename the class using the reference in `@param {RootStoreModule}` but not in the references in the first line of the comment.

```
class RootStoreModule {
  /**
   * A dead comment to {RootStoreModule} (nothing here), `RootStoreModule` (only sintax) (1°)
   * @param {RootStoreModule} -> Cool here everything works, except tooltip (2°)
   */
  private method(){}
}
```

How to get syntax highlighting, Code Lens and refactoring in a class reference in a summary / description of a comment in a typescript file in Visual Studio Code?

That is, how to obtain the resources (refactoring, ...) that are available on the second line also on the first.

Answer (score 0):

[Angular Language Service](https://angular.io/guide/language-service) provides code editors with a way to get `completions`, `errors`, `hints`, and `navigation`.

Features:

1. Autocompletion
2. Error checking
3. Quick info and navigation

Get the extension from `visual studio code` `Marketplace`

Comment: Thank you but that is not the feature I am looking for.
apparently this will come with [ts 4.0](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35524)